# Trying to execute a script (that creates folders) on remote server: “Permission denied”

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, fedora, permissions, remote

I wrote a script that should allow me to create directories with specific permissions on a remote server.

I used the command to execute the script to the remote server:

```
stan@192.168.159.133 /root/Documents/script
```

And I got this answer:

```
bash: /root/Documents/script: Permission denied
Connection to 192.168.159.133 closed.
```

I'm working on Fedora 20, and the server is on Ubuntu 18.04.1.

I tried to modify the permission on my script document with chmod:

```
chmod 777 script
```

At first I tried to execute the script with the SSL connection integrated inside of the script (you can see it in my script).

```
#!/bin/bash

#Connecting to Ubuntu Server
#ssh stan@192.168.159.133

#specifying the directory where I want to create my two directories
cd /home/stan

#Creating the first directory "PublicFolder" and assigning permissions
mkdir PublicFolder
chmod -R 606 PublicFolder

#Creating the first directory "PrivateFolder" and assigning permissions
PrivateFolder
chmod -R 604 PrivateFolder
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated: There seems to be a `mkdir` missing on the penultimate line of that script.

Comment: Kusalananda, you're right. It's in my script though, I guess I deleted that line by mistake while I was editing my post. I'm sorry about that. Thank you!

Comment: Does the user `stan` have _access_ to the script at all on the server? The `/root` directory is usually (and should be) inaccessible by non-root users.

Comment: I would expect `bash: stan@192.168.159.133: command not found`.

Comment: Which machine is the script on (local or remote)?

Comment: Please don't set permissions to `777`. Instead use `chmod +x script`. You don't want to give everyone write permission.

Comment: I changed the permission (I think it's something I'll remember!). The local machine has the script, so anybody has access to the script on the server.

Comment: I found the answer: I executed this command on my local machine: `ssh stan@192.168.159.133 'bash -s' < script` . I don't really know why it works yet, but I'll work on that! Thank you very much for all of your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few possibilities that could be causing your issue.
1. There is no *ssh* in front of your command. Try this:
`ssh stan@192.168.159.133 /root/Documents/script`
2. you are logging in to the remote server as *stan* and trying to execute a script that is under the user *root*. Stan will not have access to this script, even if you change the permissions on the file *script*.
3. Permissions flow down the directory tree with the *x* attribute. By default, */root* will **not** allow access to anything below it.
`ssh stan@192.168.159.133 ls -ld /root`
`ssh stan@192.168.159.133 ls -ld /root/Documents`
You will probably see something like this:
`drwxr----- root root  /root`
Or, more likely, you will get a permission denied error, because stan can't see in to /root.
Possibilities:
**BAD** root:192.168.159.133 # *chmod -R a+rx /root*
**Better** move /root/Documents/script /tmp & set execute permissions on /tmp
**BEST** cread a directory called /share, move /root/Documents/script to /share and set r+x permissions on /share